# Check number and date fields do not appear when manually entering contributions

Tags: civicontribute

Since upgrading to version 4.7.27 the boxes for entering check number and date do not appear when you enter a contribution in the back end with a payment type of check.  It used to be that once you selected payment type check, the options to enter this information would appear.  They don't anymore.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide!

Leslie

Comment: I can concur with Karin, It is still there for us too. We are using:WP 4.8.3, CiviCRM4.7.27, iATS 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

That would definitively be a bug - but I just had a look and check number is still there: [image]

Perhaps something other than Core (an extension, custom code) is hiding your check number field?

Comment: Thanks - I'll try disabling extensions and see if that helps.  We don't have any custom code that would affect this.  I should have also mentioned in my original question that I'm using drupal (not wp) but I don't suppose that makes much difference in this instance.  Thanks again...

Comment: Leslie, did you ever find out what would help with this?  This has been an issue for us all along, and it looks like an answer was never posted to your question here.